# Exporting SSRS report based on document map

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a ssrs 2008 report that has a document map based on the main group on the report.  The document map works fine for navigating the report on the screen, but we'd like to print one group of the report.  I beleive Crystal Reports offered this functionality.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document map is used only to navigate in the report.

A workaround could be to create a link to the group, which will call the same report, and filter it to show only the clicked group with the rest of parameters remaining the same.

Then the user can use document map to go to the group, click it to trigger the filter and print or export it to a file.